# Time module referenced before assignment, But is not, Time module is imported ahead. Maybe this is a bug

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, time

The Code below returns this error:

time.sleep(random.randint(0,10))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'time' referenced before assignment

I have imported time module, and never faced any error with such simple operation, i dont get whats going wrong here. Am i looking at a bug here.
Also i checked running this code in pycharm, it shows indexation error on first two time.sleep() and not the last one.
Also the Function is running fine without time.sleep(), so probably there is nothing wrong with the function.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import random
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('../chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver')

def parse_xyz(city):
    driver.get('www.xyz.org')
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys(city, Keys.ENTER)
    except:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/header/nav/ul[2]/li[1]/div/div/div[1]/input').send_keys(city, Keys.ENTER)    
    driver.implicitly_wait(8)
    time.sleep(random.randint(0,10))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]/a').click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(8)
    time.sleep(random.randint(0, 10))
    z_dir = []
    for i in range(50):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[8]/div/div[1]/div/div/a[2]/div['+i+']').click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        time.sleep(random.randint(0, 10))
```

Error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/samar/PycharmProjects/Scrapo/main.py", line 62, in <module>
    parse_xyz('Delhi NCR')
  File "/home/samar/PycharmProjects/Scrapo/main.py", line 9, in parse_z
    time.sleep(random.randint(5,10))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'time' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Pls give the full error traceback

Comment: i have updated the question with traceback @AribMuhtasim

Comment: error is in parse_z , and the code provided is parse_xyz?

Comment: Please provide the full code

Comment: yeah i changed it, to post it on stackoverflow, it contained some sensitive info, parse_z, and parse_xyz were names changed for forums. That isnt the error & the function works fine without time.sleep

Comment: this is the full code, below this it creates a dictionary thats it and appends it to z_dir @AribMuhtasim

Comment: @samar2170 where is your function is define means it is after `parse_xyz` or above libraries that you have mention

Comment: function is called at the bottom of the page. FYI the function runs just fine without time.sleep

Comment: @samar2170 in your traceback it says error is from the line 'parse_z('Delhi NCR')'. However in your code we don't see any function parse_z(city'). So most probably you are receiving error from a different module or function.

Comment: already answered in the comments @Roy

Comment: In that case this does not make any sense. Can you try importing like this `from time import sleep` and invoke `sleep(random.randint(0, 10))`. On a seperate note, it is never a good idea to wait a random amount of time for synchronisation. We should use explicit wait in case implicit wait is not cutting it.

Comment: Your solution worked @Roy. But what went wrong here, can somebody explain?